# QuickBooks .NET SDK

Tags: .net, oauth, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am developing a .Net client application that will integrate to the customer's QuickBooks Online (QBO) and the customer's synced desktop data (QBD).

Can I use QBXML?  Is this still supported by Intuit?  If so, how do I get an App Login and App ID for my new application?  Are these still available to new developers?

If I need to use the .NET SDK for REST v2.0, how do my Customers get the Access Token and the Access Token Secret string values if the app is not web based?  I understand how this works with oAuth CallBacks from a web app but how does this work from a fat client .Net app?  I have attempted to connect using "oob" for out of band callbacks, but this results in an error during the final phase of authenticating on the Intuit web site.

Answer (score 0):

All information is present in our docs. 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb

QBXML is available for non SAAS applications and custom integrations.

Intuit supports OAUTH using browser only(web apps). Not sure that fat client .net app will work.

Edit-
There is a sample app provided by Intuit for generating OAUTH secret and token:
You can download sample app from the GITHUB-

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code 
Set your app keys in web.config and debug it for more information.

Comment: On this page of the documentation:https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0100_ipp_.net_devkit/0299_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis the doc says to create the oAuthRequestValidator.  How does my customer know what values to use for AccessToken and AccessTokenSecret?

Comment: Edited my answer above.